# Using HttpClient in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `Angular HttpClient` to fetch data from APIs. I have to make many `get` requests and all of them are independent. But if even one of them fails, I have to terminate the process. With `promises`, it would have been easy, I could have used `Promises.all`. But with `HttpClient` I am not sure how to do this. At present, I am nesting all of my requests, which seems to me as a bad coding practice. Here is a sample code which I am doing. Please note all my api calls are independent.

```
self.authService.getDuration().subscribe(
    function(data: Array<IDuration>) {
        self.duration = data;

        self.authService.getUserData().subscribe(
            function(data: any){
                self.userData = data;

                //more api calls in nested manner
            },
            function(err){
                console.log("error");
            }
        );
    },
    function(err){
        console.log("error");
    }
);
```

Is there a better way to do this, so that I don't have to nest all of my independent api calls and get a failure message if any of the APIs fails?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html. Also, use arrow functions rather than anonymous functions, and stop using this `self` dirty trick.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, forkjoin was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use forkJoin

```
let character = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
let characterHomeworld = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/1');

forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld])
.subscribe(results => {
    //results[0] is our character
    //results[1] is our character homeworld
}, err => {
    //handle error here
});
```